# Auto increment in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have an existing database using PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

When users become a member on my website, I need the system to create a unique membership number for them using a five digit number. for e.g 83773. I guess it is like generating a random password except I only want numbers for my members. This ID number has to be unique to each member.

Would it be possible for me to set the primary key to auto_increment in my user table and set it to start at 10000 and then auto increment every time a member registers?

Also, is there a maximum number that the primary key ID number would go up to?

Is this a reliable and safe way to use the primary key ID number as a membership number?

Comment: Some of the people below answered that there is no upper limit to the primary key, but I would assume that the upper limit is the maximum size of the data type you selected...maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't int be limited to a max value of 4294967295 then?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Please pick up the accepted answer. I think this is the one http://stackoverflow.com/a/18942684/248616

Answer (score 270):

There are possible steps to enable auto increment for a column. I guess the phpMyAdmin version is 3.5.5 but not sure.

Click on ***Table*** >  **Structure** tab > Under **Action** 
Click Primary (set as primary),
click on **Change** on the pop-up window, scroll left and check **A_I**. Also make sure you have selected **None** for **Default**[image]

Comment: Since the auto-inc feature was removed from the Operations tab, it appears this is how to implement it now. Thanks, @AmitKB.

Comment: However when I tried that I got this error:  `Query error:
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: The message is clear, you might be trying to have more than one auto column.

Comment: However when I tried that I got this error: `Query error:
#1062 - ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Looks like that columns already have values, you can remove values from that column and try it.

Comment: Had a similar issue and this fixed my problem

Comment: wow, so simple. why has nobody mentioned this? took me so long to find an answer like this. by far the best answer.

Comment: Yaakov Ainspan set primary key first then set auto increment

Comment: It requires to set the column as key.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Make sure your "Attributes" i.e. Table > Structure tab > Action >  Change > Attributes is set to "Empty". If it is not, then first make it Empty, save it, and then redo your action and enable A_I check button and then save it. 

I got the same error i.e. "Query error: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key" but after I followed the above steps, it worked.

Comment: You can also uncheck the primary key option.

Answer (score 53):

In phpMyAdmin, navigate to the table in question and click the "Operations" tab. On the left under Table Options you will be allowed to set the current AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: when i do this my only two options regarding adding auto_increment are "move table to" or "copy table to". i neither want to move or copy the table, but simply add auto_increment. what is going on?? i'm using MySQL v5.6.

Comment: @oldboy I get the same as you. Perhaps they removed the feature in newer versions of XAMPP PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 22):

Just run a simple MySQL query and set the auto increment number to whatever you want.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=10000
```

In terms of a maximum, as far as I am aware there is not one, nor is there any way to limit such number.

It is perfectly safe, and common practice to set an id number as a primiary key, auto incrementing int. There are alternatives such as using PHP to generate membership numbers for you in a specific format and then checking the number does not exist prior to inserting, however for **me personally** I'd go with the primary id auto_inc value.

Answer (score 13):

1. In "Structure" tab of your table
2. Click on the pencil of the variable you want auto_increment
3. under "Extra" tab  choose "auto_increment"
4. then go to "Operations" tab of your table
5. Under "Table options" -> auto_increment type -> 10000

Answer (score 2):

In phpMyAdmin, if you set up a field in your table to auto increment, and then insert a row and set that field's value to 10000, it will continue from there.

Answer (score 2):

@AmitKB, Your procedure is correct. Although this error

Query error: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

can be solved by first marking the field as key(using the key icon with label primary),unless you have other key then it may not work.

Comment: It has been so long since I played with phpMyAdmin I forgot how to do this. Thanks for the fix to this secondary issue. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this on the latest phpmyadmin is by using the following command;

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `col_name` INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col_name`);
```

Answer (score 1):

(a)Simply click on your database, select your table. Click on 'Operations'. Under the 'table options' section change the AUTO_INCREMENT value to your desired value, in this case: 10000 the click 'Go'. (See the image attached)

(b)Alternatively, you can run a SQL command under the SQL tab after selecting your table. Simply type 'ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;' then click 'Go'. That's it!!
[SETTING AUTO INCREMENT VALUE image(a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hPap.png)

[SETTING AUTO INCREMENT VALUE image(B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxBmL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a maximum value (other than choosing a datatype which cannot hold large numbers, but there are none that have the limit you're asking for). You can check that with LAST_INSERT_ID() after inserting to get the id of the newly created member, and if it is too big handle it in your application code (e.g., delete and reject the member).

Why do you want an upper limit?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `wp_terms`, `wp_termmeta` and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables, which had all their ID's not set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

To do this go to phpmyadmin, click on the concern database, `wp_terms` table,  click on structure Tab, at right side you will see a tab named `A_I(AUTO_INCREMENT)`, check it and save (You are only doing this for the first option, in  the case `wp_term` you are only doing it for `term_id`).

Do the same for `wp_termmeta` and `wp_term_taxonomy` that will fix the issue.

Comment: It seems like you think the OP is using WordPress, where did you find that information? I cannot find any references to WP in the question.