# How to create second primary column ( Auto Increment)

Tags: php, mysql

i m having the table like this

```
------------------------
Id  |  MergeId  | name |
------------------------
1   |   M1      | Riya |
2   |   M2      | diya |
3   |   M3      | tiya |
------------------------
```

MergeId is already assigned as Primary key, now i want a new column ID (AutoIncrement), but when i try to create its shows me like "cant create already a table should have only one primary key"
but i cant change my MergeId from Primary to other constrains.
please someone help, thankyou

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE  `merge_info` ADD  `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
ADD INDEX (  `id` ) ;
```

**Error**

```
#1068 - Multiple primary key defined
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question; you can of course make a column auto-incrementing without it being a primary key. Is that really the only issue here, or is there something else?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to add the auto-increment column.

Comment: How to do that auto increment without primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be an auto-increment column - a columns need to either be the primary key or having an index. Add an index to the `id` column. Then you can make it auto-increment

```
alter table merge_info add index id (id);
ALTER TABLE merge_info modify COLUMN id int auto_increment;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2363/1)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates you can only have one primary key per table.  You may be able to have a composite primary key (that is a primary key composed of multiple columns).  You can add constraints to make a column behave similarly to a primary key.  You can require NOT NULL and UNIQUE, add AUTO_INCREMENT semantics, and add an index on the column (or composite group of columns).

(Clarification: you can apply apply AUTO_INCREMENT to individual columns ... the constraints and indexing can be done on composites as well as single columns).

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one primary key. You can however set the column to auto increment. I think what your trying to get at is joining that table with another, is that correct? I believe they are called foreign keys but I think thats only with MSSQL, never used them with MySQL.

Auto increment is a matter of what your doing. PHPMyAdmin you just select it as one of the column attributes.

PHPMyAdmin:

[Auto increment in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665571/auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin)

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID2 int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

As per Jim:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID2 int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UNIQUE (ID2)
)
```

After thought:

Check out this link, it may be of more benefit than any of this other stuff. Please be more specific next time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Might want to suggest adding UNIQUE constraint as well.  This would more closely match the semantics of a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: No No No! You can only have one auto_increment column on a table and it must be a key.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Thanks for catching that!