# Can I add two rows auto increment in two ids of same column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can I add two rows auto increment in two ids of same column

Let suppose I have an ID as Primary key and CID as secondary Key How I can add Auto increment function on both ids is there any solution in phpMYadmin using MySQL database For Example I want this is it possible???

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_project_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Key` (`cid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_project_category`
--
```

Comment: Check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665571/auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665571/auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin). Hope it helps.

Comment: @MattiasValpenSingmyr I want auto increment in two ids ??

Comment: It is possible BUT why would you have an AI secondary key if you can use the PK fine....

if you use a secondary key it's most likely to be a FK

Comment: @MikeM. I updated the Question I want same I mentioned.. is it possible

Comment: I got this error when i select two AI 
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @MarkBaker I want it have you any idea

Comment: Why do you want it? Given that both columns would have the same value anyway, what's the point?

Comment: or you have any solution to set id = cid
@MattiasSingmyr

Comment: One possible way of doing this is to have an ON INSERT trigger that populates the second `ai` column with the value of the first `id` column

Comment: @MarkBaker or you have any solution to set id = cid

Comment: Will you please guide me how I can do this @MarkBaker

Comment: Define your `cid` column as a standard `int(11) not null` (without the autoincrement), then something like: `CREATE TRIGGER ins_cid BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_project_category FOR EACH ROW SET @cid = @id;`

Comment: @MarkBaker Nothing happens :(

Comment: Try `CREATE TRIGGER ins_cid BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_project_category FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.cid = NEW.id;`

Comment: Though I still don't understand why you actually need this at all

Comment: I want to define cid for Category page with isset cid
and 
id for product page to show products @MarkBaker

Comment: This really smells like very bad database design.... if this is a cross reference table, then it should have a single autoincrement id for uniqueness, and then foreign keys `product_id` and `category_id` referencing the `id` values in your `products` and `categories` tables respectively

Comment: assuming `CID` would be categoryid
there should be a category table with an `ID`
as a project **HAVE** to be in one of the desired categories in that table, you'd have to work with a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT`.
If you do that, you're always secured that the `CID` is with one of the categories