# Can't add new records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I can create a record using this, but it won't automatically update my ID column to allow for new records. Would i need to add in a expression to update the counter? Or is there a button or switch to make using phpmyadmin to automatically create the new id on submit?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "message";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO adminmessages (UserName, Message, Score)
    VALUES ('SammyWest', 'Test1', '100')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Table Schema

```
    1   IDPrimaryIndex  int(255)            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
Primary Primary
Unique Unique
Index Index
Spatial Spatial
Fulltext Fulltext
More
    2   UserName    varchar(255)            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
Primary Primary
Unique Unique
Index Index
Spatial Spatial
Fulltext Fulltext
More
    3   Message varchar(255)            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
Primary Primary
Unique Unique
Index Index
Spatial Spatial
Fulltext Fulltext
More
    4   Score   int(255)            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
Primary Primary
Unique Unique
Index Index
Spatial Spatial
Fulltext Fulltext
More
```

Comment: Please post your table schema.

Comment: Can you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18942684/1548932

Comment: Ahh yes! The A_I was the only thing i was missing, testing it now! :D

Comment: For your table schema  use show create table adminmessages; and post the result

Comment: Sweet works! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You must define your id column to be an auto-increment primary key field using :

```
ALTER TABLE adminmessages CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```